# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

My app works fine on the simulator but crashes with this message running it   on iPhone device. Why and how can I fix it?
How can I find on what code line the app crashes?

```
func playButton(playButton: UIButton!) {

    var image = UIImage()

    if activePlayer == 1 { image = UIImage(named: "x.png")! }
        else { image = UIImage(named: "o.png")! }

    playButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't know what's wrong. // On a general note, my solution would be to convert every forced unwrapping done with `!` to safe unwrapping with `if let` or `guard`, handle the possible errors in `else` clauses and/or `do try catch` mechanisms, then you'll see immediately what's wrong and where is the problem.

Comment: can you post the code where the app crashes?

Comment: The error is on the if line :    if activePlayer == 1 { image = UIImage(named: "x.png")! }

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, the part where it could generate this error is probably the forced unwrapped UIImage. Modify your code like this to find out:

```
func playButton(playButton: UIButton!) {
    let imageName: String
    if activePlayer == 1 {
        imageName = "x.png"
    } else {
        imageName = "o.png"
    }
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
        playButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        print("error while retrieving image named '\(imageName)'")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried Eric's code. The app works fine on the simulator but prints the message running it on iPhone device.

Comment: I tried Eric's code. The app works fine on the simulator but prints the message running it on iPhone device: "error while retrieving image named 'x.png'". It means that UIImage(named: imageName) is nil running on a device and image running on simulator!!?? the rest of the app runs well on both environments. What is different and what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The IOS device is case sensitive while the simulator isn't. So, I replaced the image names to the exact file names ("X.png" and "O.png" instead of "x.png" and "o.png"). Now, UIImage(named: "X.png") is not nil and the app works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Here, we would use *if let* and have a look at below

```
func playButton(playButton: UIButton!) {

var image = UIImage()

if let player =  activePlayer {
  if player == 1 {
     image = UIImage(named: "x.png")! }
```

} else { image = UIImage(named: "o.png")! }

```
playButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

}

(or) if you are using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7, *guard* is good choice too.

Comment: The problem is not with the activePlayer. It's value is not nil. The app crashes on the { image = UIImage(named: "o.png")! } line. For some reason UIImage(named: "o.png")!  is nil when running on device and not nil when running on the simulator.